# How to copy all files inside a remote directory?

Tags: java

The command to copy a single file remotely is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sshpass -p sbsiz scp '/home/surendra/Desktop/remote_backup.txt' root@192.168.59.115:/home/");`

But how is the syntax to copy all files inside the `/home/surendra/Desktop` directory ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try wild card option? like `scp /local-directory/* root@<some-host>:/remote-directory`

In your case run following.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh","-c", "sshpass -p sbsiz scp '/home/surendra/Desktop/*' root@192.168.59.115:/home/"});
```

Comment: cannot try it till now cause the machine is inaccessible